# How to send XElement object across AppDomains

Tags: c#, appdomain

I have an application which loads external assemblies from different dll files. I'm load assembly to another domain created before. All assemblies returns XElement object and i need use this object for another methods in main AppDomain, but XElement object have not Serializable attribute, that's why i can't send this object as is. It is very important to get XElement object from external libraries. I tried use serialization for this, but every time i got fails.

I tried create some wrap class. This class just creates stream from XElement and i trying read from this stream in main domain but this stream is closed at that time.

I will be very happy if somebody will help me solve this issue.
Thanks in advanced.

```
private XElement CallModule(string modulePath, string moduleName, 
  Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
{
  AppDomainSetup moduleDomainSetup = new AppDomainSetup();
  moduleDomainSetup.ApplicationBase = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.RelativeSearchPath;
  AppDomain moduleDomain = 
    AppDomain.CreateDomain("moduleDomain", null, moduleDomainSetup);

  try
  {
     Module remoteobj =  (Module)moduleDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(
       HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(modulePath),
       moduleName + "." + moduleName);
     Module.WrappedStream remoteResult = 
       remoteobj.Execute(queryString["command"], parameters);

     XElement res = XElement.Load(remoteResult.Stream);
     return res;
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    throw ex;
  }
  finally
  {
    AppDomain.Unload(moduleDomain);
  }
}
```

Comment: I find that strange, the XElement confirms to the IXmlSerializable interface - ( public class XElement : XContainer, IXmlSerializable )  Have you tested just returning string or int, does that work for you.

Comment: @orn, XElement is not binary serializable nor marshal by reference which is needed to be able to use it cross-appdomain.

Comment: Yaroslav, your sample missing portion of the code that runs in the other AppDomain and creates stream. So it is not possible to diagnose why that particular call fails. (I don't think that it is good idea anyway - seem my answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [XElement.Save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb538479.aspx) to save it to a TextWriter or Stream

Answer (score 0):

You can't use XElement cross AppDomain boundary. Potential reason - XElement can represent huge object tree/huge amount of data that have to be marshaled across AppDomain boundary.

While you can get your code to work (i.e. via saving to stream and reloading) it may not be the best idea. You'll lose context for the element (i.e. parent) and you may inadvertently serialize/de-serialize huge amount of data. Consider refactoring in such a way that you deal with XElement's data inside new AppDomain where it is created and than return your custom objects (serialzable or marshal by ref) to main AppDomain.

Notes:

- I assume your sample code is just sample, creation/tearing down of AppDomain to call single method is not the fastest thing on Earth. May be perfectly ok if it's for one time operation, but if it repeats with any non-trivial frequency make sure to check if performance meets your goals.
- You don't need `catch`/`throw` if you just need `finally` (again assuming actual code does more than `throw`)

Comment: I would gladly refused to use application domains, but when i'm trying load dll library in main domain, then this dll file becomes locked, and i can't delete / replace this library until process will not be killed. It is also important issue because i should be able replace old library to new in runtime

Answer (score 0):

```
Module remoteobj =  (Module)moduleDomain.CreateInstanceFromAndUnwrap(
       HttpContext.Current.Request.MapPath(modulePath),
       moduleName + "." + moduleName);
     Module.WrappedStream remoteResult = 
       remoteobj.Execute(queryString["command"], parameters);

     XElement res = XElement.Load(remoteResult.Stream);
     return res;
```

Rather than trying to serialize XElement, is it possible to serialize modulePath, moduleName and parameters and later recreate the XElement object with the modulePath, moduleName and parameters.

Also can you try this with Command Pattern?